# Jquery удалить строку до символа

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть строка такого вида

```
var str = ?type=residential&price_type=1&course_type=1
```

Нужно обрезать значение до первого амперсанд , т.е. на выходе должна быть вот такая строчка. При условии, что мы не знаем длинну.

```
var str = &price_type=1&course_type=1
```

Каким образом можно сделать на jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярка вам поможет:

```js
var str = "?type=residential&price_type=1&course_type=1";
str = str.replace(/^[^&]+/, ''); // если & нет в строке, вернется пустая строка
console.log(str);
```

Или так (если нет &, то вернет всю строку):

```js
var str = "?type=residential&price_type=1&course_type=1";
str = str.substring(str.search('&'));
console.log(str);

var str = "?type=residential+price_type=1+course_type=1";
str = str.substring(str.search('&'));
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Используем функцию:

```js
var str = "?type=residential&price_type=1&course_type=1";
console.log(str.substr(str.indexOf("&")));
```

Comment: При условии, что мы не знаем длинну. Или нужно сначала длину посчитать? Думаю должен быть метод без длинны

Comment: я исправил, теперь все работает